# Power Query - Merge values from 2 different queries based on vlaue in another query

Tags: powerquery

I have 3 merge queries. Merge query 1 will get different sets of values depending on the value of one of it's columns.

If MergeQuery1-Column A = Value 1 then merge query 1 with columns B,C and D from query 2 else if MergeQuery1-Column A = Value 2 then merge query 1 with columns X,Y and Z from query 3

Can this be done.  I realize this will probably require some M code in the advanced editor so any examples would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach without writing any complex M code manually.

- Duplicate MergeQuery1.
- In the first query, MergeQuery1, remove all rows with Column A = Value 2,
- in the duplicate of MergeQuery1, remove rows with Value 1.
- Merge the first query with the query 2,
- merge the duplicate with query 3.
- Append the two results.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.